# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Tags: windows, ubuntu, .net-core

.NET core 3.0 when runtime get an System.PlatformNotSupported Exception 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5EHW.png)

Also im tryed on ubuntu 19.04, same exception

Comment: `PlatformNotSupportedException` is a very general exception that means what it says: what you are trying to do is not supported on the platform. Can you provide more details about exactly what it is that the code is trying to do? Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it here?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/misery-around-platformnotsupportedexception-1b890c74a08a

Answer (score 0):

NetCore 3.0 does not support BeginInvoke method

[-] `NewMessages?.BeginInvoke(this, response, null, null);`

[+] `NewMessages?.Invoke(this, response);`